# modular forms mod p and their liftings

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Deligne in "Courbes elliptique: Formulaire (d’après J. Tate)" computes the ring of modular forms mod $p$. He proves that if $p>3$, then the space of modular forms is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p [c_4, c_6]$ but, for example, for $p=3$ one has $\mathbb{F}_3 [b_2, \Delta]$ where $b_2$ is of weight $2$ and $\Delta$ is of weight $12$. In particular, there is a nonzero weight $2$ modular form mod $3$. This modular form should not lift integrally and my question is: does it lift mod $9$? If yes, what is the minimal $k$ such that $b_2$ does not lift mod $3^k$?

Comment: @ThePhoenix but doesn't that proposition imply that there are no holomorphic modular forms of level one defined over $\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$ since $3$ does not divide 12?..

Comment: @ThePhoenix Oh, I'm sorry. I'm bad at reading and I'm bad at english.. Never mind.. Thank you!

Comment: @ThePhoenix However, there are nonzero modular forms mod $9$ with the constant different from $1$. For example, we can multiply the Hasse modular form by 3 (I mean this $b_2$ modular form) and it will be a modular form mod $9$. Is it correct?

Comment: @ThePhoenix Sorry, I did not get this comment.. What is $c$?